# How can we pass parameters in javascript class methods

Tags: javascript, class

I have created a class in javascript, and I want to have methods as member of that class with parameter. How can we do?
I have done following code in order to create a class and methods -

```
function Classname(){
   a1 = 100;
   this.a2 = 0;
}

Classname.prototype.method1 = function (message) {
   alert(message);
};

//Creating object
var obj1 = new Classname();
```

But when I am calling the method as -

```
obj1.method1("Hello");
```

Then I am getting error that `Uncaught ReferenceError: messgae is not defined`.

Comment: The code provided by you should work. Is it a typo? (`messGAe`?)

Comment: yup code actually works fine

Comment: Don't forget to `var a1` if you don't want it to become global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmk6e/). Is it a verbatim copy?

Your error message seems to reference a misspelled variable, `messgae`.

Comment: @CodeCrypt Do you have any other code above or below your snippet?

Comment: @CodeCrypt: It looks very much as though the code you're trying to execute has `alert(messgae);` instead of `alert(message);` which you've entered in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: messgae is not defined

Are you sure that you use exactly the same code in your environment as you provided in the question?

You obviously use a name which can't be resolved due to a typo in the name (`messgae` → `message`).